# Java StringTemplate Using File From Outside Directory

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Templates/
├── Foo/
│   ├── Foo.st
├── Signature.st
```

Here's what the `Foo.st` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <p> Some Text </p>
    </div>
    $Signature()$
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Java code with `StringTemplate`:

```
STRawGroupDir dir = new STRawGroupDir("Templates", '$', '$');
ST st = dir.getInstanceOf("Foo/Foo");
System.out.println(st.render());
```

But the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <p> Some Text </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the `Foo` template to be able to properly reference the signature template?

If I put `Signature.st` inside the `Foo` directory then the above code works just fine, but I can't do that as I'll have many templates that will reference the `Signature` template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
...
$/Signature()$
...
```

Template calls are resolved relative to the calling template. Starting a template call with prefix `/` will make the template call absolute - which is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a really easy way to do this. I have now the following directory structure:

```
Templates/
├── Foo/
│   ├── Foo.st
├── Main.st
├── Signature.st
```

Here's my `Main.st`

```
$ templates : { template |
$(template)()$
}$

$Signature()$
```

And here's my java code:

```
STRawGroupDir dir = new STRawGroupDir("Templates", '$', '$');
ST st = dir.getInstanceOf("Main");
st.add("templates", Arrays.asList("/Foo/Foo.st"));
st.render();
```

Now I can pass in any number of templates and this works perfectly.